# folder/file share between ubuntu gnome and lubuntu

Tags: shared-folders, sharing

can you tell me how to share a folder/file between lubuntu 15.10 and ubuntu gnome 15.10? the ubuntu one is connected to the internet via WIFI and the lubuntu machine is connected via cable to the router (same router). i installed gigolo and samba on both but i cannot figure it out. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking reputation point to comment on your question in order to ask for more information... I can't really help you with setting up file sharing via Samba.

What I can do is suggest you use [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) or [Demonsaw](http://demonsaw.com/) to share files on local network. Both applications should be able to recognize other machines on a local network without needing a running internet connection.

Comment: Then there's [Dukto](http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11) and [giver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/giver/) but I haven't tried those.